# Switching to hide and show between Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have 2 forms Form1 and form2.First time Form2 is being load by  below code and this is my sign in page..

```
application.run(new form2())
```

But after sign in i want to load another form Form1.How will i load it.If i am creating new From2() this is making new form not showing respected controls there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this inside Form2 (or wherever you check the login data)

```
private void btnLogIn_OnClick(...)
{
    if(/* perform credential test here */)
    {
        (new Form1()).Show(); // create and show the other form
        this.Close(); // close this form
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Login invalid!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
form.Show();
```

Comment: Sorry for miss write.. I want to Load Form1, after sign in. New objct is giving me fresh form i am not seeing my textbox and buttons on forms.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

`Form2.Show();`

Comment: Sorry for miss write.. I want to Load Form1, after sign in.

Comment: .Show() function is not giving suggestion in C3.net 2005.